# How do you add Tailwind CSS classes to the <html> and <body> tags in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3, tailwind-ui

I am trying to make a custom 404 error page for my Nuxt 3 app using tailwind.

I'd like the page to fill the screen on all devices with the 404 centred vertically and horizontally, but I can't get it to be centred vertically. It is always at the top of the page even when I use `h-screen` or `h-full` in a wrapping `<div>`.

In an example in of such page in Tailwind UI components, it says the "*this example requires updating your template*":

```
    <html class="h-full">
    <body class="h-full">
```

How do I easily add tailwind classes to `html` and `body` tags for a specific `page.vue` in Nuxt 3?

I have tried adding the following in the `page.vue`:

```
<script setup>
useHead({
  htmlAttrs: {
    style: 'html: h-full'
  },
  bodyAttrs: {
    style: 'body: h-full'
  }
})
</script>

<style>
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

On the `useHead` composable documentation. There is a `bodyAttrs` parameter. That should help you add any custom classes in the body tag. If you want to add a class on the HTML, you can use the `htmlAttrs` parameter.
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head#usehead

```js
useHead({
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: 'your-body-class',
  },
});
```

Here is a working example. Hope that helps you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ts3sbx?file=pages%2Findex.vue